# How to store Nodes in GraphRepository as well as Neo4j-Spatial Index

Tags: playframework, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I am using **Neo4j-Spatial** with **Spring** data in a **Play!Framework** application.

I have a @NodeEntity of type *User* which I want to store in the database as well as a spatial index for location based queries.

The examples that I have seen create a Node using the GraphDatabaseService:

```
Node stadiumNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode();
```

and then add this Node to the spatial index:

```
Index<Node> index = graphDatabaseService.index().forNodes(indexLayerName, config)`;
stadiumNode.setProperty("wkt", String.format("POINT(%s %s)", lat, lon)); 
index.add(stadiumNode, "dummyA", "dummyB");
```

However, the Node does not have a specific type (such as *User*) associated with it. In order to do that, I have to first create `interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>` :

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

and then add the User nodeEntity to the repository:

```
User user = new User();
userRepository.save(user);
```

However, this creates **3 nodes** (1 in the spatial index RTree, and 2 in the neo4j graph). What is the correct way of doing this? I just want 2 nodes:

1. One node of type *User* in the neo4j graph
2. One node containing location information associated with the above node.